# How to find a number of workdays between two dates in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

I have two dates as `datetime.date` objects, what is the most Pythonic way to find a number of workdays between these two dates (including starting and excluding ending date)? For example:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

d1 = date(2019, 3, 1)
d2 = date(2019, 5, 6)
# The difference between d2 and d1 is 46 workdays
```

Writting a loop comes to my mind:

```
workdays = 0
for i in range((d2 - d1).days):
    if (d1 + timedelta(days=i)).isoweekday() <= 5:
        workdays += 1
```

However, I think there is a simpler way to solve this problem.

Comment: How to you define a workday? To you include/exclude holidays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the numpy function busday_count:

```
from datetime import date
import numpy as np

d1 = date(2019, 3, 1)
d2 = date(2019, 5, 6)

days = np.busday_count( d1, d2 )
print (days)
```

or

```
from datetime import date,timedelta
d1 = date(2019, 3, 1)
d2 = date(2019, 5, 6)
daygenerator = (d1 + timedelta(x + 1) for x in range((d2 - d1).days)) # generate all days from d1 to d2
print (sum(1 for day in daygenerator if day.weekday() < 5))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

It does not take holidays,.. into account:

```
import numpy as np
np.busday_count(d1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), d2.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```